# Recurrence Relation Solving Problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, recurrence-relations, order-theory

Can anyone help me in solving this complex recurrence in detail?

$T(n)=n + \sum\limits_{k-1}^n  [T(n-k)+T(k)] $

$T(1) = 1$.

We want to calculate order of T.

I'm confused by using recursion tree and some maths induction.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Should $k$ range from $1$ to $n-1$ instead of $n$?

Comment: I put in the $\LaTeX$ for you.  Please note that $k \neq K$ and $n \neq N$ but I left them as they were.  I presume you meant them to be the same.  Also please check the upper limit of the sum.

Comment: what is $T(0)$ then?

Comment: @user153695, it doesn't really work that way. Firstly, your function is still undefined for $n \ne 1$. Secondly, you have to show us what you've done so that we can help you.

Comment: How come that $k$ varies from $k-1$ to $n$?

Comment: Putting $k-1$ under the summation sign does not indicate the variable you are summing over.  Having $k=$ something will tell that and show what to start at. That is why I put in $k=1$  What should it start at?

Comment: It isn't any form of Quicksort, there you average over the possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use generating functions. Define $g(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} T(n + 1) z^n$, write yout recurrence as:
$$
T(n + 2)= n + 2 + 2 \sum_{1 \le k \le n + 1} T(n)
$$
Multiply by $z^n$, sum over $n \ge 0$ and recognize the resulting sums:
$$
\frac{g(z) - T(1)}{z}
  + z \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z} \frac{1}{1 - z} + \frac{2}{1 - z}
  + 2 \frac{g(z)}{1 - z}
$$
go get, written in partial fractions:
$$
g(z) = \frac{3}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - 3 z} - \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - 2 z}
$$
Thus:
$$
T(n) = \frac{3^n}{2} - 2^{n - 2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Starting with:
$$
T(n) = n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left[T(n-k) + T(k)\right]
$$
The two terms in the square braces are the same; one is counting down and the other counting up, so:
$$
T(n) = n + 2\times \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} T(k)
$$
To find the order of $T$, we need to compare $T(n)$ to $T(n-1)$.
$$
T(n-1) = (n-1) + 2\times \sum_{k=1}^{n-2} T(k)
$$
So we rearrange terms in the definition of $T(n)$:
$$
\begin{align}
T(n) &= [(n-1) + 1] + 2\times \left[ \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-2} T(k)\right) + T(n-1)\right]\\
&= 1 + \left[(n-1)  + 2\times \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-2} T(k)\right)\right] + 2\times T(n-1)\\
&=1 + T(n-1) + 2\times T(n-1)\\
&= 3\times T(n-1) + 1
\end{align}
$$

Thus, $T(n)$ is $O(3^n)$.  Given that $T(1) = 1$, we see $T(n) = 3^n/2-1/2$.

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong?  Do you see something wrong in my proof?  Do you know of a value were $T(n) \neq 3^n/2-1/2$?  Or do I have the wrong initial recursive function definition?